# Required view with id for field was not found but id exists

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-databinding

I have a little problem.

I'm trying to `BindView` with the id `ongoing_call_layout`.
I have that id, it exists and its a `ConstraintLayout` object in xml.
When running the program it acts like the id "ongoing_call_layout" doesn't exist.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project and also using `findViewById` instead of `BindView` but still, it says that the id doesn't exist.

In the code itself its bolded (AndroidStudio do know where the id is).

Below is the related code

Here is my `OngoingCallActivity.java` (where the error comes from):

```
@BindView(R.id.ongoing_call_layout) ConstraintLayout mOngoingCallLayout;
.
.
.
 ButterKnife.bind(this);
.
.
```

The error:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chooloo.www.callmanager/com.chooloo.www.callmanager.ui.activity.OngoingCallActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'ongoing_call_layout' with ID 2131362055 for field 'mOngoingCallLayout' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.
```

Here is my `on_going_call.xml` (where the id comes from):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ongoing_call_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.OngoingCallActivity">

    <!-- Call Timer -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guide_status_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_stopwatch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guide_status_bar"
        tools:text="00:00" />

    <!-- Caller Number (Temporary) -->

    <!-- Caller Pic -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_caller"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/text_caller"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text_caller"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_stopwatch">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_placeholder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:tint="@color/selector_button_icon"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:civ_border_width="0dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Caller Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_caller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:paddingRight="10sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline4"
        android:textColor="?attr/iconColor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_status"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Jesus" />

    <!-- Call Status -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guide_eye_level"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text_caller"
        tools:text="@string/status_call_incoming" />

    <!-- Hold Button -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guide_eye_level"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.44" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_hold"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/flat_button_size"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_oval"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/flat_button_padding"
        android:tint="@color/selector_button_icon"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_add_call"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_speaker"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_mute"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guide_eye_level"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32999998"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pause_black_24dp"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <!-- Mute Button -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_mute"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/flat_button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/flat_button_size"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_oval"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/flat_button_padding"
        android:tint="@color/selector_button_icon"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button_hold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_hold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button_hold"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mic_off_black_24dp"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <!-- Speaker Button -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_speaker"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/flat_button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/flat_button_size"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_oval"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/flat_button_padding"
        android:tint="@color/selector_button_icon"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button_hold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_hold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button_hold"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_volume_up_black_24dp"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <!-- Keypad Button -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_keypad"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/flat_button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/flat_button_size"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_oval"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/flat_button_padding"
        android:tint="@color/selector_button_icon"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button_add_call"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_add_call"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button_add_call"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dialpad_black_24dp"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <!-- Add Call Button -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_add_call"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_oval"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/flat_button_padding"
        android:tint="@color/selector_button_icon"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_keypad"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_hold"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <!-- Answer Button -->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/answer_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_call_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/green_phone"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:fabCustomSize="72dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:maxImageSize="36dp" />

    <!-- Reject Button -->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/reject_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_call_end_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/red_phone"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:fabCustomSize="72dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:maxImageSize="36dp" />

    <!-- Guidelines -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I cant make the declaration of mOngoingCallLayout `Nullable` because its necessary.
By the way, that bug only started happening out of no where after i merged some code from server but all the code that's related to this is still the same.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you call `setContentView(R.layout.ongoing_call_layout)` before the `ButterKnife.bind(this)`?

Comment: Some ridiculous error. Or you bind you activity before serContentView, or you put wrong layout in setContentView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try several things

1. Rebuild project
2. Clean project
3. Invalidate Caches/ Restart

You can also try ButterKnife Plugin = Settings -> Plugins -> Android ButterKnife Zelezny;

To access plugin menu, place your keyboard cursor on the activity name in `setContentView(R.layout.your_activity)` and press `ALT + INSERT` it will be last or second last option `Generate ButterKnife Injections`

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you for helping but still no change

Comment: @RoeiEdri if this didn't help or fix your problem why did you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how it works for butterknife, however, to enable data binding in your application you need to declare the following in the `android` section of your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

And then you need to wrap your `on_going_call.xml.xml` with `layout` as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ongoing_call_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

And yes, as stated in the comment, you need to `setContentView` in your activity.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Do you have any other solution?